# Reading suffix rules

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I just came across the british dictionary that is available here...

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/british-english-dictionary/

The source refers to affix and suffix rules those have lines like the following:

```
SFX B te bility ate 
SFX B e ability [^a]te 
SFX B 0 bability [^aeio][aeiou]b
```

Can someone explain how to read these rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox uses [Hunspell dictionaries](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/fichiers_speciaux/hunspell). The lines you quote use this format:

> SFX flag stripping suffix condition morphological_description

All three lines define class B suffixes (only apply to words marked with this class in the `.dic` file). The first line defines the suffix `-bility` that can be added to words ending with `ate` and replaces `te`. Example: `communicate`, strip `te`, add `bility`, get `communicability`.

Second line lists `-ability` as a suffix for words ending with `te` but not `ate` ([regular expressions syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) used here), here only `e` is removed at the end of the word. Example: `excite`, strip `e`, add `ability`, get `excitability`.

Finally the third line lists `-bability` as a suffix for word ending with a consonant followed by a vowel followed by `b`. Zero indicates that this suffix is simply added to the word, it doesn't replace anything (seems strange in this particular case, I think that the last letter should be stripped). This rule seems to be unused for the letter `b` but `accept` => `acceptability` falls under a similar rule for the letter `t`.

Comment: # http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/13805
# Is there a book / webpage that will explain all these rules used in the british dictionary ?